# Error: Cannot find module "net" webpack wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, webpack, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

i get the mentioned error on my wordpress project. it started when i was testing out the woocommerce api for the first time. i had made a get request in a js file, nothing fancy, just tried console logging the data i wanted (customers to be specific) to test out.

i had searched this error and it seems like something is wrong with my webpack config, but i'm not sure what it is. i'm relatively new to webpack so all the info i've been reading just hasn't settled in my head yet. i tried several suggestions from webpack's git (https://github.com/request/request/issues/1529), and a few i've found here on stack but can't get the error to go away.

```
conole error: Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "net"

webpack error: 

var net = __webpack_require__(!(function webpackMissingModule() { var e = new Error("Cannot find module \"net\""); e.code = 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'; throw e; }()));

//my webpack config

const path = require('path'),
settings = require('./settings');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    App: settings.themeLocation + "js/scripts.js"
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, settings.themeLocation + "js"),
    filename: "scripts-bundled.js"
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['babel-preset-es2015']
          }
        }
      }, {
        test: /\.json$/,
        loaders:   'json-loader'
      }
    ]
  }
}
```